# Не получается выровнять последний элемент

Tags: html, css

Делаю учебный проект и не получается выровнять последний элемент  вот эта надпись должна быть по середине экрана , но с расстоянием (красная стрелка) 70px; не могу догадаться какие параметры задать

```css
.feinman {
  height: 890px;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.feinman__image {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  width: 867px;
  height: 637px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/feynman.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 0;
}

.feinman_feinman__title {
  width: 648px;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  line-height: 1.15;
  font-size: 120px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

.feinman__link {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 36px;
  top: 50%;
  right: 48px;
}

.feinman__link-color {
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: black;
}

.feinman__subtitle {
  line-height: 51px;
  font-size: 36px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 70px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section class="feinman">
  <h1 class="feinman_feinman__title">Метод Фейнмана</h1>
  <h2 class="feinman-subtitle"> Выучить и не забыть</h2>
  <div class="feinman__image" alt="Фейнмана"></div>

  <div class="feinman__link">
    <a href="#" class="feinman__link-color">Подробнее &rarr;</a></p>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

И как я понял сама надпись метод феймана тоже не по центру находится. Надо и ее подправить

Comment: вы где эту штуку увидели ? покажите

Comment: У вас классы в html не соответствуют классам css
Например в html:
<h2 class="feinman-subtitle"> Выучить и не забыть</h2>
А в css:
.feinman__subtitle

Comment: Какую  штуку ?  Да , кстати , точно не соответствует